# $\frac{\max(1,xy)}{y} = x$: Did I just create a fractal?

Tags: maxima-minima, fractals, desmos

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6hfyqc6ks9

Did I just create a fractal? Again, the function is $\frac{\max(1,xy)}{y} = x$.

[image: Here's what it looks like on Desmos]

[image: Here's what it looks like on WolframAlpha]

Even uncannier version, from the alternative form with "sgn" that Wolfram provided: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rikex4bvld

Comment: Pretty cool Josh. How do you know that it’s fractal?

Comment: Not sure if it's mathematically correct, though. Could it just be that I tricked Desmos into attempting to plot all real numbers on the coordinate plane or something, and what I'm seeing right now is simply a memory issue? Because if $xy > 1$ and $y \ne 0$, then I'm pretty sure this would just simplify to $x = x$.

Comment: Hmmm. Your guess is as good as mine. Try it on wolframalpha.com?

Comment: It looks like the equation should be true if $xy\geq 1.$ Not sure why Desmos graphs it the way it does.

Comment: Now see. Yeah, I'm almost certain that this is not mathematically correct, because multiplying both sides by y and graphing $\max(1,xy) = xy$ simply produces the graph of $y = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Thomas, what is "beq"? I'm assuming it's a typo for "not equals to"?

Comment: Always wait a moment for edits, since we can’t see MathJax errors until after we post.

Comment: Sorry about that. My bad.

Comment: The repeating pattern occurs between powers of two. This leads me to guess that this is a floating point issue, and not directly related to the equation

Comment: Why, shawn, I tried it on WolframAlpha and it's also a hot mess.

Comment: Added pictures for convenience's sake.

Comment: Ok. Well, you’ve stumbled upon a fractal pattern of some kind, perhaps. Whether it’s new or not is not part of my knowledge. Best of luck to you.

Comment: What is your definition of "fractal"?  In the mathematical literature, the term remains undefined (Mandelbrot proposed a definition 40 years ago, but abandoned it pretty quickly when it failed to capture the kinds of objects which were of interest).  And even if the answer is "yes", what next?  Simply labeling something "fractal" doesn't actually tell you very much.  What is the next step?  What do you get by determining whether or not it is fractal?

Answer (score 10):

You have definitely created a strange fractal-like behavior, but not in the equation itself -- rather in Desmos's plotting software :)

The problem with this equation is that it is true not for a one-dimensional curve of points, but rather for the two-dimensional **space** of points $(x,y)$ where $xy \ge 1$. Algebraically:
$$
\frac{\max(1, xy)}{y} = x
\iff \max(1, xy) = xy \iff xy \ge 1.
$$

The true plot of this is as follows:

[image]

Graphing software -- including Desmos -- is usually optimized for the case of plotting a curve, rather than a 2-dimensional space of points. It is likely that is the reason for the weird behavior.

FWIW, Desmos does warn us that something might be up with this plot, as shown by the following warning in your screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have identified the regions as being delimited by powers of $2$ and graphs of $y=2^k/x$. The issue is with the implementation of their max function. If you change it to $\max(0,xy)/y=x$, you can extend the pattern all the way down to the origin:
[Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/txdfsqj2ed)
[image]
The clean lines make up the true "fractal". But I think this is the end of the line for me, because I have no idea why max would have an issue understanding that if $a\approx 2,b\approx 2$ then clearly, $\max(ab,0)=ab$.

Comment: Bonus: infinite zoom of the straight lines https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2lokf2dvan